# How to consume WCF Web Service from native C code without manually writing a C++ CLI "bridge"?

Tags: c#, c, c++-cli

I've been doing this before by

- Generating C# WCF WS Client with WSCF Blue from wsld-file to WSClient.dll
- Writing (manually) C++ CLI WSClientBridge.dll that has:

  - structs used in native C code (w/ arrays etc) for types in WSClient.dll
  - conversion from managed types to native
  - conversion from native types to managed
  - exported functions that:

    - convert native structs to managed classes
    - calls C# method in WSClient.dll
    - convert managed classes to native structs
    - return the native struct(s)
- Writing C code that calls exported functions WSClientBridge.dll and uses native types defined in WSClientBridge.dll

This is both error-prone, difficult with complex hierarchical data and takes lots and lots of time.

The question is: How to do this better in terms of time spent and error proneness?

Answer (score 1):

One time-saver here, both during development and at runtime, would be to remove the intermediate managed WCF client.

A native toolset/SDK such as [gSOAP](https://www.genivia.com/dev.html) might fit the bill, dependent upon your licensing requirements. (Open-source and commercial versions are available.)

Comment: thanks! i looked into it already. this would eliminate both C++/CLI "bridge" and managed dll.